# Add a string to each individual string in a list

Tags: python, string, list

Simple addition of a string and a list of strings yields the error `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`. Is there a more elegant way to do the following (e.g. without the loop)?

```
list_of_strings = ["Hello", "World"]
string_to_add = "Foo"

for item, string in enumerate(list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings[item] = string_to_add + string

# list_of_strings is now ["FooHello", "FooWorld"]
```

Comment: That being said, your solution is probably the most efficient, as it does not require creating an intermediate list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use comprehension:

```
list_of_strings = [s + string_to_add for s in list_of_strings]
```

Answer (score 2):

try using map

```
list_of_strings = ["Hello", "World"]
string_to_add = "Foo"


print map(lambda x:string_to_add+x,list_of_strings)
```